# Determine the direction an object is actually moving

Tags: unity-game-engine

In unity I am trying to compare the players actual direction with the direction they are facing and wish to move in but having major issues trying to find the actual movement direction.

I can determine the facing direction very easily with:

`wishDir = transform.localEulerAngles;`

But I cannot figure out how to get the objects movement direction so that I can compare. I have tried:

`transform.InverseTransformDirection(rb.velocity);`

I would expect this to be equal to 0,90,0 when I move to the right however it is equal to 0,0,0 (although jumps when there is acceleration).

How can I determine the direction an object is moving in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can determine the facing direction very easily with:
>
> ```
>    wishDir = transform.localEulerAngles;
> ```

This is already quite odd to me. [`localEulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) is a rotation in Euler space notation in degrees per axis `x,y,z` .. this is no "direction".

Usually if you want the direction you are looking in you would rather use [`transform.forward`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html)

```
wishDir = transform.forward;
```

---

And then

```
transform.InverseTransformDirection(rb.velocity);
```

should indeed return the direction in local space.

Note that the `Debug.Log` beautifies (rounds) this value to make it more human readable. If you want the exact values you could try and log e.g.

```
var relative = transform.InverseTransformDirection(rb.velocity);
Debug.Log(relative.ToString(F4));
```

which should print the values always with 4 digits after the decimal point.